# Customizable Behavior using Unity Interception c#

Tags: c#, unity-container, aop, interception, unity-interception

I trying to create Separate Customizable Interception Behavior for specific scenarios such as
trace logging, exception logging , Performance logging and combination of mentioned.

However , When I created a Custom behavior with Method as Attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class LoggingBehaviorAttribute : Attribute , IInterceptionBehavior 
{
   public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tracing.....");
        string ClassMethodName =
            string.Format("{0}::{1}", input.MethodBase.ReflectedType.Name, input.MethodBase.Name);

        //Logger
        log.Addlog(string.Format("Before {0} method execution ", ClassMethodName));
        log.Addlog("The Parameter Passed : " + GetParameterInfo(input));
        
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Before {0} method execution ", ClassMethodName));
        Console.WriteLine("The Parameter Passed : " + GetParameterInfo(input));

        IMethodReturn msg;

        try
        {

            Stopwatch Timer = new Stopwatch();

            //Start the Timer to capture the performance of the Method .
            Timer.Start();

            //Execute the Method after logging 
            msg = getNext()(input, getNext);
            
            //stop the timer
            Timer.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("The Performance metric for the Method {0} is {1} ", 
            ClassMethodName,
                Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

And in my Class I have mentioned the behavior over the method that needs interception .

```
Public class Calculator : Icalculator 
{
    [LoggingBehavior]
    public float Add(float x, float y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public float Subtract(float x, float y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }
}
```

In My Main class the Interception is applied to both the class methods instead of one the Add() Method .

Main Class Code : -

```
public static main()
{
     var container = new UnityContainer();

     container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

     container.RegisterType<Icalculator, Calculator>(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingBehaviorAttribute>());

     var Calc = container.Resolve<Icalculator>();

     //Performing Addition
     float result = Calc.Add(123, 343);

     //Performing Subraction
     float result1 = Calc.Subtract(123, 343);
}
```

Can Someone point to me out where I am making mistake in customization . Is it something wrong with Registration of container ?
Please add in your thoughts ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
public static main()
{
     var container = new UnityContainer();

     container.RegisterType<Icalculator, Calculator>();

     var Calc = container.Resolve<Icalculator>();

     //Performing Addition
     float result = Calc.Add(123, 343);

     //Performing Subraction
     float result1 = Calc.Subtract(123, 343);
}
```